# How to integrate ChatGPT plugins with my node js server?

Tags: node.js, plugins, openai-api

I have developed a Node.js server to get finance data by using the Polygon.io ChatGPT plugin.
If I integrate klarna plugin, it works but not with polygon plugin.
Here are my code with Polygon plugin.

```
var http = require("http");
const axios = require("axios");
const {OpenAI} = require("langchain/llms/openai");
const {initializeAgentExecutorWithOptions} = require("langchain/agents");
const {SerpAPI, AIPluginTool, RequestsGetTool, RequestsPostTool} = require("langchain/tools")
const {Calculator} = require("langchain/tools/calculator");
const {ChatOpenAI} = require("langchain/chat_models/openai");

// At the top of the file

const server = http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    if (req.method === "POST") {
      // Handle post info...
      let body = "";
      req.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
      });
      req.on("end", () => {
        var question = body.split('"')[3];
        console.log(question);

      const tools = [
        new RequestsGetTool(),
        new RequestsPostTool(),

        AIPluginTool.fromPluginUrl("https://polygon.io/.well-known/ai-plugin.json", "70DnLnda2q81MoTZpXTAalXJ0dXS4Ovp")
          .then((tool) => {
            // Make sure the tool has a description before using it
            if (!tool.description) {
              throw new Error("AIPluginTool is missing a description.");
            }
            return tool;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error initializing AIPluginTool:", err);
            throw err; // Rethrow the error to handle it appropriately
          }),
      ];


      Promise.all(tools)
      .then((resolvedTools) => {
        const agent = initializeAgentExecutorWithOptions(
          resolvedTools,
          new ChatOpenAI({ temperature: 0, openAIApiKey: "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" }),
          { agentType: "chat-zero-shot-react-description", verbose: true }
        );

        return agent.then((exe) => {
          return exe.call({ input: question });
        });
      })
      .then((response) => {
        res.end(response.output);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error running the agent:", err);
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.end("Internal Server Error");
      });
```

If I ask "What is the stock of AAPL?", then the question variable in this code is the question I asked.
The result I get is

```
}
[chain/end] [1:chain:agent_executor > 2:chain:llm_chain] [3.55s] Exiting Chain run with 
output: {
  "text": "Thought: I need to find the last dividend of AAPL.\nAction: I will use the Polygon 
API to get the dividend data for AAPL.\n"
}
[chain/end] [1:chain:agent_executor] [3.55s] Exiting Chain run with output: {
  "output": "Thought: I need to find the last dividend of AAPL.\nAction: I will use the 
Polygon API to get the dividend data for AAPL."
}
```

Why this happens?
If I use another plugin like klarna, it works well.
Here is the working code with klarna ChatGPT plug

```
var http = require("http");
const axios = require("axios");
const {OpenAI} = require("langchain/llms/openai");
const {initializeAgentExecutorWithOptions} = require("langchain/agents");
const {SerpAPI, AIPluginTool, RequestsGetTool, RequestsPostTool} = require("langchain/tools")
const {Calculator} = require("langchain/tools/calculator");
const {ChatOpenAI} = require("langchain/chat_models/openai");

// At the top of the file

const server = http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    if (req.method === "POST") {
      // Handle post info...
      let body = "";
      req.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
      });
      req.on("end", () => {
        var question = body.split('"')[3];
        console.log(question);

      const tools = [
        new RequestsGetTool(),
        new RequestsPostTool(),
        AIPluginTool.fromPluginUrl("https://www.klarna.com/.well-known/ai-plugin.json")
      ];


      Promise.all(tools)
      .then((resolvedTools) => {
        const agent = initializeAgentExecutorWithOptions(
          resolvedTools,
          new ChatOpenAI({ temperature: 0, openAIApiKey: "sk-jlbN4HSHNMTOuk0Nw2A****************nkV1n1hSq" }),
          { agentType: "chat-zero-shot-react-description", verbose: true }
        );

        return agent.then((exe) => {
          return exe.call({ input: question });
        });
      })
      .then((response) => {
        res.end(response.output);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error running the agent:", err);
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.end("Internal Server Error");
      });
```

Thanks